# Powershell $? in do until loop

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to make a loop for joining a Windows domain in PowerShell with usage of `$?`, which should return false/true if last command returned error or not.

This is what I got:

```
Add-Computer -DomainName "domainname.local" -Credential "admin"

$MaxAttempts = 0
do {
    if ($? -like "false" -and $MaxAttempts -lt 5) {
        $MaxAttempts += 1
        Write-Host "Attempt" $MaxAttempts "out of 5"
        Add-Computer -DomainName "domainname.local" -Credential "admin"
    } else {
        Write-Host "test"
    }
```

Problem is when I have first command outside of that `do`/`until` loop it's returning true even when I get an error.
But when I add this command to `do`/`until` loop it returns false as expected but that way im running that command twice and that's not I want.

Can someone explain me this sorcery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) `$?` contains true or false depending on whether or not the previous PowerShell statement completed successfully. The last PowerShell statement before you check the value of `$?` inside the loop is `$MaxAttempts = 0`, which changes the value of `$?` to true (because the assignment operation succeeded), even if the `Add-Computer` statement before that failed.

I'd recommend adjusting your loop to something like this:

```
$MaxAttempts = 0
do {
    Add-Computer -DomainName "domainname.local" -Credential "admin"
    $success = $?
    if (-not $success) {
        $MaxAttempts++
    }
} until ($success -or $MaxAttempts -ge 5) {
```